# Unable to evaluate the selected expression ? - Eclipse lib debug error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, workspace

I get this error while debugging with eclipse and try to evaluate the variable or expression. Is it even possible to check the value of external library used in our project?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Did you check Build path? It seems about build path problem or class path.
of course you can see variables whether external library or yours

Comment: I guese, if build path were wrong the project would not build.